# nginx cannot find module error in node server

Tags: node.js, reactjs, nginx, react-router

I have a server with react in the frontend and node in the backend, the development mode everything works fine, but after trying to put it into production with ngnix, I am having problem with the images that are in my backend. In the output of the web console I get the following errors.I think it's a nginx configuration problem, but I'm just learning to use it

these is the console error:

[image]

these is my directory App:

[image]}

[image]

these is my locations ngnix config:

```
       location / {
            root /var/www/production/front-end/build;

            # First attempt to serve request as file, then
            # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
            #try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
            try_files $uri $uri/  /index.html;
    }
    location /graphql {
            #proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            #proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            #proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
            #proxy_pass http://localhost:4000/;
            #proxy_ssl_session_reuse off;
            #proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            #proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
            #proxy_redirect off;
    }
```

Comment: The screenshot shows the `images` directory of `back-end` directory. If I am not mistaken, your `nginx` config is looking for images in `front-end` build. Also, please add your `build/dist` directory screenshot.

Comment: Kn_pavan, Is it possible that nginx loads the images that are in a directory of my backend?

Comment: No. Unless you're loading both dist to `nginx` by accident. Give a try with separate docker containers if possible

Comment: I'm not publishing the service with docker yet. At the moment I put github project in the root of the ngnix, but pointing to the folder of the buil de react

Comment: Ok. I feel that the issue is mostly with the build directory. Please recheck nginx directories. Since the Node back-end and nginx front-end are on two different posts, there is not much chance for backend to serve the images in local. If you are `upstream`ing the request to the Node instance, then that's a different case again